# How can I setup grub password in rhel7?

Tags: grub2, password

So I am trying to set password for grub to prevent entry of single-user mode who might have direct physical access to my machine. I am working on RHEL7, and the redhat portals show that this feature was added in RHEL7.2

I ran following command:

```
grub2-mkpasswd-pdkbf2
```

which prompted me to enter the password. After I entered the password I got hash code which I copied.

Now I need to know in which configuration file do I need to paste that hash code? Should it be `/etc/grub.d/40_customs`?

But what entries should I make in this file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
2. Locate the boot entry that you want to protect with password by searching for lines beginning with `menuentry`
3. Remove the `--unrestricted` parameter from the menu entry block
4. Save and close `grub.cfg`

Now even booting the entry requires entering the root username and password.

Source: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Protecting_GRUB_2_with_a_Password.html

Comment: There are important notes in the original source about grub.cfg being a generated file.